# Exit a bash switch statement

Tags: bash

I've written a menu driven bash script that uses a `switch case` inside of a `while` loop to perform the various menu options. Everything works just fine. Now I'm trying to improve the program by performing error testing on the user input, but I cannot seem to make it work...

The problem is I don't know how to properly break out of a switch statement, without breaking out of the while loop (so the user can try again).

```
# repeat command line indefinitely until user quits
while [ "$done" != "true" ]
do
   # display menu options to user
   echo "Command Menu" # I cut out the menu options for brevity....

   # prompt user to enter command
   echo "Please select a letter:"
   read option

   # switch case for menu commands, accept both upper and lower case
   case "$option" in

   # sample case statement
   a|A) echo "Choose a month"
        read monthVal
        if [ "$monthVal" -lt 13 ]
        then 
           cal "$monthVal"
        else
           break # THIS DOES NOT WORK. BREAKS WHILE LOOP, NOT SWITCH!
        fi
        ;;
   q|Q) done="true" #ends while loop
        ;;
   *)   echo "Invalid option, choose again..."
        ;;
   esac
done
exit 0
```

The program works fine when the user enters a valid month value, but if they enter a number higher than 13, instead of breaking the switch statement and repeating the loop again, the program breaks both the switch and while loop and stops running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the body of that `case` into a function, and you can `return` from the function at will.

```
do_A_stuff() {
    echo "Choose a month"
    read monthVal
    if [ "$monthVal" -lt 13 ]
    then 
       cal "$monthVal"
    else
       return
    fi
    further tests ...
}
```

Then

```
case $whatever in
a|A) do_A_stuff ;;
```

Answer (score 14):

Hitting `;;` will terminate the case statement. Try not doing anything at all:

```
a|A) echo "Choose a month"
     read monthVal
     if [ "$monthVal" -lt 13 ]
     then 
        cal "$monthVal"
     fi
     ;;
```

Comment: The problem with this is when I have more than one `if` statement, and need to run multiple tests against user input. Even if the first one fails, the programming logic will still continue through the other `if` statements as if nothing was wrong.

Comment: @Moses Can you post an example of multiple `if`s? Perhaps you can combine with `&&` as in `if [ test1 ] && [ test2 ]; then ...; fi`

Comment: Yes, I could do that (and do for some commands), but when I need 3+ pieces of information to perform a single action, the `if test` statement gets very long, very fast. It would be much simpler to perform the validation one at a time (especially since that would allow me to echo to the user what the specific problem is, rather than just say "one or more of your inputs didn't work..."

Comment: @Moses: after running each test you can check the return code with `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ; run_test2 ; fi `

Answer (score 14):

I think what you mean to do with `break` is "quit this case statement and restart the while loop". However, `case ... esac` isn't a control-flow statement (although it may smell like one), and doesn't pay attention to `break`.

Try changing `break` into `continue`, which will send control back to the start of the while loop.

Comment: the correct answer to the OP should have been yours replace "break" with "continue", thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:  Wrap the code in a one-trip for-loop:

```
#! /bin/bash

case foo in
  bar)
    echo "Should never get here."
    ;;

  foo)
    for just in this_once ; do
      echo "Top half only."
      if ! test foo = bar; then break; fi
      echo "Bottom half -- should never get here."
    done
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Should never get here either."
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no point in breaking, you can omit the else break statement altogether.

The problem occurs when there is code that runs after the point where you would have broken. You'd want to write something like that

```
case $v in
a) if [ $x ]; then bla; else break; fi;
  some more stuff ;;
b) blablabla ;;
```

What I usually do (because creating a function is such a hassle with copy pasting, and mostly it breaks the flow of the program when you read it to have a function somewhere else) is to use a break variable (which you can call brake for fun when you have a lame sense of humor like me) and enclose "some more stuff" in an if statement

```
case $v in
a) if [ $x ]; then bla; else brake="whatever that's not an empty string"; fi;
   if [ -z "$brake" ];then some more stuff; brake=""; fi;; 
   #don't forget to clear brake if you may come back here later.
b) blablabla ;;
esac
```